# Netlify can't find react-bootstrap/Navbar

Tags: reactjs, navbar, gatsby, react-bootstrap, netlify

I built a static site using the Gatsby framework and I'm trying to deploy it using Netlify. Netlify seems to deploy everything fine initially and runs the gatsby build command. However, I keep running into this error:

```
12:36:51 PM: failed Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 33.697s
12:36:51 PM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
12:36:51 PM: Can't resolve 'react-bootstrap/NavBar' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
```

I use react-bootstrap throughout my project and the only place I use NavBar is in a header component in the components folder. Here are the relevant lines:

```
import NavBar from "react-bootstrap/NavBar"
<NavBar>...</NavBar> //etc
```

It appears that the issue is strictly with the react-bootstrap NavBar element and no other elements seem to have the same issue. So I'm tempted to think there's something wrong with the installation of react-bootstrap on Netlify's end.

My react-bootstrap version (in package.json)

```
"react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
```

Things I have tried: Setting my NODE_VERSION environmental variable to match my local environment. Deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and re-running npm install.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Trying changing how you import NavBar to:

```js
import { Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
<Navbar>...</Navbar> //etc
```

Comment: Same issue. Also forgot to include this was also part of the error message: "If you're trying to use a package make sure that 'react-bootstrap/NavBar' is installed. If you're trying to use a local file make sure that the path is correct."

Comment: And this only happens during deployment? The site runs fine locally using `gatsby build` then `gatsby serve` on `localhost:9000`?

Comment: Yep just ran `gatsby build` and `gatsby serve` locally and everything shows up fine on `localhost:9000` with no error messages. @apena